# What will be the output?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
 1. int *a;
 2. a=new int[2];
 3. cin>>a[0];
 4. cout<<a<<"\n";
 5. cout<<&a<<"\n";                
 6. cout<<*a;
```

What will be the output of 5th line?
I know that 4th line will give the address of first element of array a and 6th line will give the value of the first element of array a. But I cannot figure out whose address is given by 5th line.

Thanks.

edit: This is the output after compiling.

- 4
- 0x5d2158
- 0x28fefc
- 4

4 is taken as input.
0x5d2158 is the output of 4th line
0x28fefc is the output of 5th line
4 is the output of 6th line

Comment: Did you run the code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can compile it and find out yourself. Then look for `&` symbol in `c++` on internet.

Comment: i compiled it and it is giving an address but I cannot figure out whose address its giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will give the address of the pointer `a` itself. Pointers also take space in the memory to store the address of actual data they are pointing to, in this case which is an integer array.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of each line of your input:

1. `int *a;` declares a pointer to an int
2. `a=new int[2];` allocates array of ints of size two and assigns the address of  the first element(index 0) to pointer `a`
3. `cin>>a[0];` reads value from standard input and assigns it to first (index 0) element of array `a`
4. `cout<<a<<"\n";` prints address of **where `a` points to**, meaning address of first element(index 0) of your array of ints of size 2
5. `cout<<&a<<"\n";` prints address at which pointer `a` is stored (i.e. location of the **pointer** in the memory)
6. `cout<<*a;` prints the value `a` points at, meaning **first element of `a` array**

Answer (score 0):

It will give address of first element. That's it

Comment: No, it is not giving the address of first element.

Comment: It could be possible it giving the address where name of array i.e. a is stored.

Answer (score 0):

It will give address of pointer 'a' it self. explain in diagram. Address of a is '0x7fffa28413c8' hence output of &a is 0x7fffa28413c8.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPobm.png

Comment: question is about the 5th line not 6th.